# single touch not working on ios ionic but double touch is working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

This is my first ionic app, i have made an hybrid app using ionic .it is working fine in android but in ios:- ion-tab are not working i have to double tap on it to work.clicking on img,href not working on single touch in ios,but double touching on it is working, scrolling up down is also not working .what would be the problem..please help

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top " id="wall-tabs">

<!-- Dashboard Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Social TV" ng-class="hide_class" icon-on="adwall-on" icon-off="adwall-off" href="#/tab/adwall">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-adwall"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Chats Tab -->
<ion-tab title="My Channel" icon-off="my-wall-off" ng-class="hide_class" icon-on="my-wall-on" href="#/tab/mywall">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-mywall"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!--ad_Post Tab-->
<ion-tab icon-off="post-off" ng-class="hide_class" icon-on="post-on" href="#/tab/ad_post">

    <ion-nav-view name="tab-ad_post"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>



<ion-tab title="Following" icon-off="following-off" ng-class="hide_class" icon-on="following-on" href="#/tab/following">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-following"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<!-- Notification tab Tab -->

<ion-tab title="Notifications" icon-off="notification-off"  ng-class="hide_class" icon-on="notification-on" href="#/tab/notifications" badge="data.badgeCount" badge-style="badge-assertive">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-notifications"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

this the ion-tab code on which i have to double touch it to work on iphone...but on my nexus this same code is working fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: Please add some of your code so we can elaborate on what's wrong.

Comment: in android that ion-tabs are working cool.but in ios i have to double tap on it

Comment: Maybe you could add some more information about your ionic cli,  just use: `ionic info`.